# :readonly key of belongs_to method doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to use `:readonly key` as it described in [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to):

```
belongs_to :project, readonly: true
```

That's my code with model associations define:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :feed, inverse_of: :articles, readonly: true
end
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :articles, inverse_of: :feed, dependent: :delete_all
end
```

These two snippets look alike.
But when I test my models in `rails console` it doesn't work:

```
irb(main):001:0> article = Article.first()
ArgumentError: Unknown key: :readonly. Valid keys are: :class_name, :class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :remote, :dependent, :primary_key, :inverse_of, :foreign_type, :polymorphic, :touch, :counter_cache
```

I have Rails v. 4.2.0, if it's matter.

What am I doing wrong?
Why Rails doesn't interpret this argument?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is out of date. The up to date equivalent is

```
User.belongs_to :feed, -> {readonly}, inverse_of: articles
```

The lambda is used to build the scope. Anything you can usually use on relations, including `readonly`, is available here.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of usage of `readonly` was removed in rails 4.1.2. you will have to use readonly method

eg:

```
user = User.joins(:todos).select("users.*, todos.title as todos_title").readonly(true).first
user.todos_title = 'clean pet'
user.save! # will raise error
```

search "readonly" in this [changelog](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.1.2/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md) for rails 4.1.2

Comment: Thank you, Vimsha. But what if I want to declarate association as read-only in model once and then just use standart ActiveRecord query (and to be sure that returned associated object is read-only)?